# Ubuntu thinks my mouse is a touchpad? Or a touchscreen?

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, touchscreen

I've seen a lot of questions where somebody's touchpad is recognized as a mouse, but I have the opposite problem: My mouse is behaving as if it was a tap/touch input.

I have a (18.04) desktop computer with no touchpad and no touchscreen, just a regular USB mouse and keyboard. Mouse clicks have a slight delay before they register (not really noticeable), and if I'm moving my mouse when I click, sometimes it triggers "tap-and-drag"; even though I've released the mouse button, it will drag the link/tab/thing I clicked on until I click again.

Here's my xinput list, notice I don't have a Synaptic touchpad in there:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Gaming Keyboard G610             id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Gaming Keyboard G610             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I have a feeling there's something I need to change or add in 
`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` or even `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf` but my attempts so far have failed.

I tried adding these two lines in the `Section` blocks for both pointers and touchpads.

```
Option "Tapping" "off"
Option "TappingDrag" "false"
```

I noticed I don't have as many options in my dconf-editor under `/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/mouse` as I've seen on other systems. I only have 4 items:

- accel-profile: 'default'
- left-handed: OFF
- natural-scroll: OFF
- speed: 0

I downloaded a "mouse and touchpad" config utility from a different distro and tried setting the drag-tolerance to 99999 (default 8) and that just made it so I can't select things in the terminal. It still does tap-and-drag.

**How can I get my mouse to behave like a mouse?**

Comment: I have switched from Unity to Cinnamon and bought a new mouse, so now `xinput` shows device id=12 as `↳ Logitech USB Laser Mouse`, but this tap-and-drag problem persists.

Comment: What's the output of `synclient`?  Ping me @Fabby after you've [edit]ed your answer to provide the info there...

Comment: What is your computer make and model?

Comment: @DMack: Stupid question: What happens when the touchpad is turned off in system settings?

Comment: @Fabby `synclient` isn't installed, so I just get "command not found"

Comment: @Christianus I did disable the touchpad in the system settings, just to be safe. If I re-enable it, I can still recreate this tap-drag thing even if I flip the "tap to click" option on or off.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I built it myself, it's got an MSI "Z270" motherboard. I didn't go out of my way to find chipset drivers or anything, could that have something to do with it?